# Как разместить label под каждым инпутом и сделать проверку на текст в поле?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно чтобы каждый label p.error находился под полем, и чтобы инпуты оставались в таком положении(у меня при добавлении label ипнуты просто сьежают)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="modal_container" style="min-width: 500px;">

    <div class="modal_close_button"><ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon></div>
    <div class="request__form">

        <p class="modal_title">Заявка на консультацию</p>

        <form class="request" id="request">
            
            <label for="your_name"><p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p></label>
            <input type="text" id="your_name" name="your_name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
            <label for="your_number"><p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p></label>
            <input type="text" id="your_number" name="your_number" placeholder="Телефон">
            <label for="your_email"><p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p></label>
            <input type="text" id="your_email" name="your_email" placeholder="e-mail">
            <textarea name="your_comment" rows="6" placeholder="Коментарий..."></textarea>

        </form>

        <div class="request__flex">

            <p class="request__policy">Нажимая кнопку «Заказать», Вы соглашаетесь с <a href="#policy">условиями обработки и хранения персональных данных</a></p>
            <button class="request__send">Отправить</button>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
.modal_container {
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 33px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
}

.modal_close_button {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #989898;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal_title span{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
}

.modal_title {
    color: #182263;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Gilroy-ExtraBold";
    user-select: none;
}

.request__form {
    padding: 30px;
}

form.request {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: grid;
    width: 700px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grig-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 30px;
}

form.request input {
    height: 50px;
}

[name="your_name"],
form.request textarea {
    grid-column: 1/3;
}
.your_number {
    grid-column: 1;
}
.your_email {
    grid-column: 2;
}

form.request input,
form.request textarea {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #989898;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: "Gilroy-Regular";
    color: #6d6d6d;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

form.request textarea {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

form.request textarea:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.request__flex{
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.request__policy{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.request__policy a{
    padding-left: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.request__send{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #182263;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium';
    width: 250px;
    height: 58px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.policy__content li{
    color: #212121;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.policy__content h1{
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.policy__content p{
    color: #212121;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    font-size: 16px;
}

p.error{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    color: #f51a1a;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно немного изменить разметку.
Вместо:
`<label for="your_name"><p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p></label><input type="text" id="your_name" name="your_name" placeholder="Ваше имя">`

Лучше сделать:
`<label class = "your_name" for="your_name"><input type="text" id="your_name" name="your_name" placeholder="Ваше имя"><p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p></label>`

Ну и подправить шаблона грида, хотя бы вот так:

```css
.modal_container {
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    padding: 33px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
}


.modal_close_button {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #989898;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal_title span{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
}

.modal_title {
    color: #182263;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Gilroy-ExtraBold";
    user-select: none;
}

.request__form {
    padding: 30px;
}
.your_name{
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
.your_number {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;

}

.your_email {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;

}
.your_comment{
 grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.request {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 700px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

form.request input {
    height: 50px;
}


form.request input,
form.request textarea {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #989898;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: "Gilroy-Regular";
    color: #6d6d6d;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

form.request textarea {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

form.request textarea:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.request__flex{
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.request__policy{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    color: #424242;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.request__policy a{
    padding-left: 3px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.request__send{
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #182263;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium';
    width: 250px;
    height: 58px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.policy__content li{
    color: #212121;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

.policy__content h1{
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.policy__content p{
    color: #212121;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    font-size: 16px;
}

.error{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    color: #f51a1a;
    font-size: 12px;
}
label{
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal_container" style="min-width: 500px;">

    <div class="modal_close_button"><ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon></div>
    <div class="request__form">

        <p class="modal_title">Заявка на консультацию</p>

        <form class="request" id="request">
            
            <label class = "your_name" for="your_name">
            <input type="text" id="your_name" name="your_name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
            <p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p>
            </label>
            <label for="your_number" class = 'your_number'>
            <input type="text" id="your_number" name="your_number" placeholder="Телефон">
            <p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p></label>
            <label for="your_email" class = 'your_email'>
            <input type="text" id="your_email" name="your_email" placeholder="e-mail"><p class="error">*не заполненое поле</p></label>
            <textarea class = "your_comment" name="your_comment" rows="6" placeholder="Коментарий..."></textarea>

        </form>

        <div class="request__flex">

            <p class="request__policy">Нажимая кнопку «Заказать», Вы соглашаетесь с <a href="#policy">условиями обработки и хранения персональных данных</a></p>
            <button class="request__send">Отправить</button>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```